# An easy way to initialize all objects in a java class

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to generate documentation for existing services.  Its a bunch of rest services.  What I would like to do is to simply create a new tag in xdoclet, that new tag will have a parameter.  something like

```
@JSONInputMessage("com.foo.bar.input")
@JSONOutputMessage("com.foo.bar.output")
```

the xdoclet will then go to that class, initialize it, dump it into Jackson to convert it to json, and then copy the resulting json into the javadoc.

All of this is simple enough.  My problem is i need a way to take in an object, then walk the fields all the way down, initializing the objects so they actually show up in the json dump.  Does anyone have an easy way to reflect thru an object and initialize all objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Podam](http://home.btconnect.com/jemosAgile/projects/podam/) initializes a java object tree with random data, but you may define a strategy or use attributes to decide the values that are set.

Simple example:

```
PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl(); //This will use the default Random Data Provider Strategy
Pojo myPojo = factory.manufacturePojo(Pojo.class);
```

Or with a strategy:

```
DataProviderStrategy strategy = new MyDataProviderStrategy();
PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl(strategy);

Pojo myPojo = factory.manufacturePojo(Pojo.class);
```

Or with attributes:

```
@PodamStrategyValue(PostCodeStrategy.class)
private String postCode;
```

and then you define the strategy class for that single attribute:

```
public class PostCodeStrategy implements AttributeStrategy<String> {
    public String getValue() throws PodamMockeryException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Would this work for you?